# Create Array and Search Through in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

Using devise, rails 3.2. I'm trying to figure out how to create an array of ids and then check if the current_user's id is included in this array.

My users have many locations through location_users. (Locations have many users through the same relationship.)

I can get a list of user_ids associated with a location without problem:

```
 @location.users.each do |u|
   puts u.id
```

However, I assume I need to output the ids to an array and check with something like this:

```
  - [user_ids].include? current_user.id
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@location.users.map(&:id).include? current_user.id
```

or rather just

```
@location.users.include? current_user
```

should work, but involves loading all location.users and then searching through the array. I would consider writing a statements that lets the database handle this.

update: here's a way how you can let the db handle it say you want to check if user 5 is in location 1:

```
LocationsUser.where(location_id: 1).find_by_user_id(5)
```

this returns either the association (instance of LocationsUser) or nil.

Comment: Just tried the following which works ok but seems a bit ott... @location.users.map(&:id).flatten.uniq.include?(current_user.id)

Comment: instead of `@location.users.map(&:id)`, try `@location.users.pluck(:id)` so you aren't creating unnecessary objects. `pluck` will automatically only select the id from the database as a bonus.